# substring a nvarchar var that have the same criteria character multiple times

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Inside a tsql stored procedure i want to substring 'x' that is nvarchar(max).

x can take values like:

```
1.000.232 or 2.1110.23444.456
```

I want to save to 'z',which is also nvarchar(max), only the middle numbers between the first and the last '.'

For example:

```
if x=1.000.232 then z=000
if x=2.1110.23444.456 then z=1110.23444
```

Comment: The solution would be to stop storing delimited strings in your database. Anything else is only a workaround. For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the index of the first and last periods and then use the **SUBSTRING()** function to find the text between them.

```
DECLARE
    @x                VARCHAR(MAX)
  , @z                VARCHAR(MAX)
  , @FirstPeriodIndex INT
  , @LastPeriodIndex  INT;

--SET @x = '1.000.232'
SET @x = '2.1110.23444.456';

SELECT
    @FirstPeriodIndex = CHARINDEX('.', @x)
  , @LastPeriodIndex  = LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@x)) + 1;

SELECT @z = SUBSTRING(@x, @FirstPeriodIndex + 1, @LastPeriodIndex - @FirstPeriodIndex - 1);

SELECT
    @x                AS x
  , @FirstPeriodIndex AS FirstPeriodIndex
  , @LastPeriodIndex  AS LastPeriodIndex
  , @z                AS z;
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b160993cdc16638d68dbc760d942c027).